# "missing authentication token" error with Authentication type set to NONE

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call a Lambda Function through AWS API Gateway. When I mention Authentication type NONE it means it is publicly accessible.Still I am getting missing authentication token error when accessing using browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL of your API - My best guess is that you are calling the wrong endpoint url.

The format should be [invoke URL]/[path to method].